# Python custom search through logfile not returning results

Tags: python, windows, search, text-files, logfile

I am using this code to try and pull out lines for log files that include key words. However the files and lines I know that contain these words aren't written into the new error files.

I originally thought my problem was because of a difference in the endline characters between windows and Linux but I have removed lines from these original files so that the Warning is the first word in the file. The lines still were not added to the error file.

I have created my own file filled with random text and 'Warning' in several places and that outputs it correctly. I have used regular expressions and they have no effect on the situation. once I get it working I will convert it to use regular expressions.

Sample file attached :
https://ufile.io/b8gf4

Any help would be great or even point me in the direction of a solution.

```
def errorSearch(filename):
    errorfile = "error" + filename
    print(errorfile)
    try:
            fileopen = open(filename, "r")
            errorfileopen = open(errorfile, 'w')
            runtest(fileopen, errorfileopen)

            return 1
    except IOError:
            print ("Error: File does not appear to exist.")
            return 0

def runtest(logfile, error):
    num = 0
    for line in logfile:
            if 'Warning' in line:
                    error.write(line)
                    num+=1
    print(num)


errorSearch("log.txt")
```

example of log file code works for the copy and pasted code but not for original text:

```
Warning event: POST Err Sensor reports DIMM_F1 disabled.                                              BIOS POST - LUN#0 (Channel#0) 
Warning event: POST Err Sensor reports DIMM_F1 failed test/initialization.                            BIOS POST - LUN#0 (Channel#0) 
Warning event: POST Err Sensor reports DIMM_F2 disabled.                                              BIOS POST - LUN#0 (Channel#0) 
Warning event: POST Err Sensor reports DIMM_F2 failed test/initialization.                            BIOS POST - LUN#0 (Channel#0) 
Informational event: BIOS Evt Sensor reports a system boot event has occurred.                        BIOS POST - LUN#0 (Channel#0) 
Informational event: BIOS Evt Sensor reports Timestamp Clock Sync. Event is first of two expected events from BIOS on every power on.                          BIOS POST - LUN#0 (Channel#0) 
Informational event: BIOS Evt Sensor reports Timestamp Clock Sync. Event is second of two expected events from BIOS on every power on.                         BIOS POST - LUN#0 (Channel#0) 
Warning event: POST Err Sensor reports DIMM_F1 disabled.                                              BIOS POST - LUN#0 (Channel#0) 
Warning event: POST Err Sensor reports DIMM_F1 failed test/initialization.                            BIOS POST - LUN#0 (Channel#0) 
Warning event: POST Err Sensor reports DIMM_F2 disabled.                                              BIOS POST - LUN#0 (Channel#0) 
Warning event: POST Err Sensor reports DIMM_F2 failed test/initialization.                            BIOS POST - LUN#0 (Channel#0)
```

Comment: can you post a sample of the input file in the question? some websites are blocked by some firewalls (mine actually :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre https://pastebin.com/UTYT8B7A here's the contents of the file.

Comment: pastebin is a no go for me. Please include a representative sample of your file _in the question_ !

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it's there now

Comment: works fine for me. Are you sure you're running it in the proper directory? I get 8 matches using _your_ code with _your_ sample...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  it works for the copy and pasted example I tried it just there but not for the original.

Comment: sorry a [mcve] is required, else we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just add strip command to filter out junk characters that might be messing with your if statement.

```
...
for line in logfile:
        line = line.strip()
        if 'Warning' in line:
        ...
```

Also, please remember to close file handles you missed them.